# Laptop overheating for no apparent reason

Tags: overheating

I have a [Tuxedo (Linux only)](https://www.tuxedocomputers.com) laptop with Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GH x 12 running Ubuntu 19.10. Recently, for no apparent reason, for instance when I am only surfing the web, the fan comes on and the Freon GNOME-extension shows a temperature of over 80°C. Previously the only time the fan came on was during a Deja.dub backup. I have cleaned out all of the air vents with a vacuum cleaner. The system-monitor app (3.32.1) shows no processes running at more than 2% CPU capacity but the resources tab shows one or more CPUs running at 100%. Therefore the system-monitor app is not helping me pinpoint what is causing the CPU to work so hard and overheat.

Could someon show me how to find out what is causing the overheating.

Comment: `top -bn1 -o %CPU | head -17` should provide the top ten processes ranked by CPU usage.

Comment: Thanks. I have saved the command for use next time the laptop overheats.